# Lightning component failing for users of specific profiles?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, profile, user

I have faced this issue for the first time ever. I have a custom button on clicking of which a lightning component gets open. It is working fine for system admin + user of specific profiles.

But for users of certain profile, clicking on the component throws the attached screen. The error which  comes up is as follows :

**This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. First, would you give us some details? (We're reporting this as error ID: )**

Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID shown here and any other related details.
An internal server error has occurred
Error ID: 2094392832-34943 (-159444901)
quickActionHandlerHelper.js failed to create component - forceChatter:lightningComponent

Please help me to get this issue resolved, this is a show stopper for my application.

[image]

Comment: Does the profiles has permissions to do what ever the component is doing?

Comment: Check the debug log if you are calling the server side controller and make sure You have handled the callback for all the scenario.

Comment: Hello @codeyinthecloud, No, the profiles do not have the same permissions. I have made the controller classes to run in system mode by ensuring the classifier of my class as public.

Comment: @sanketkumar, No debug Log is generated for this action, I have even tried using alert in the first line of the init method of my js controller of the component. It seems like the component is not even getting opened.

Comment: You seem to have gotten this wrong -- [*No, the profiles do not have the same permissions. I have made the controller classes to run in system mode by ensuring the classifier of my class as public*] -- `public` is meant to specify the access for the class, it does not ensure anything such as system mode. If the profile does not have permission to even read the object, specifying anything on class is not going to help.

Comment: I am facing this error in the subscriber org when there is no license assigned to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue today and the reason was that the controller of my component was not compiling. I had change a definition of a method that the controller was consuming, which made the controller not valid.

So I would suggest to compile all your classes when you have such issue to see if there is any compilation issue in your Org.